# How can I implement Borrow, ToOwned, or Deref for an enum?

Tags: enums, rust

I have a type that looks like this:

```
enum Name<'a> {
    Single(&'a str),
    Double(&'a str, &'a str),
}
```

And another, very similar type that looks like this:

```
enum OwnedName {
    Single(String),
    Double(String, String),
}
```

I already have a method to convert a Name to an OwnedName. However, I cannot figure out a way to implement something like `Deref` or `Borrow` for this type to convert an OwnedName back to a Name. This means I have to write the same methods twice, which is annoying. I’d like to have something that mimics the way `PathBuf`/`Path` or `String`/`str` work. I’ve tried something like this:

```
impl ops::Deref for OwnedName {
    type Target = Name;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Name {
        match *self {
            OwnedName::Single(ref s) => Name::Single(&**s),
            OwnedName::Double(ref s1, ref s2) => Name::Double(&**s1, &**s2),
        }
    }
}
```

This errors with `wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 1, found 0` on `type Target = Name`, which is completely understandable, as, well, it needs a lifetime. But I can’t provide one. So is there a way for me to use `Deref`, or `Borrow`, or `ToOwned` in this way?

Comment: Does your type compare and hash the same as `str`? If no, you can't implement `Borrow<str>`.

Comment: Is that a general rule or are you giving me advice specifically? :) I can’t compare and hash the same as `str` because I have two strings in one of my variants.

Comment: That's a rule that `Borrow` impls need to abide by (documented by Borrow). By *can't* I did mean “should absolutely not”.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to do this.

Note that `Deref::deref`'s signature says it wants a pointer to a `Name` with the same lifetime as the thing being deref'ed.  Such a value *does not exist*.  You *cannot* return a pointer to something you created in the `deref` function, either, since it can't possibly outlive its own stack frame.

The fundamental problem is that `Name` is basically a different *kind* of pointer (like `*const T` is to `&T`), but `Deref` and other traits like it *only* allow you to return borrowed pointers.  At present, this is just no way around this.

You can, however, do this if you just don't use `Deref` and other traits like it.  One possibility would be to `impl<'a> From<&'a OwnedName> for Name<'a>`.

Comment: In fact, it *is* kind of possible to return a value created inside the function from `Deref::deref`: this value must be a fat pointer. That's how `Deref` implementation on a `PathBuf` works - it returns `&Path`, which is a fat pointer to an unsized `Path` struct. Naturally, this is limited to pointers to unsized types, and unfortunately it is not possible to write an unsized enum equivalent for `OwnedName` type, so such approach won't work in this case.

Comment: Aw, ok. It’s the unsized type of `Path` inside `PathBuf` that I was trying to emulate - if I wanted to do that, I’d have to use `str` instead of `&str` here, and I can’t do that in my particular enum.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with @DK. Just adding that if your idea is to use them interchangeably, you may not need to have an `OwnedName` at all. 
You can define Name to accept both `&str` and `String`:

```
enum Name<T> where T:Borrow<str> {
    Single(T),
    Double(T, T),
}

// these both work now
let _a1 = Name::Single("hello");
let _a2 = Name::Double(String::from("hello"), String::from("world"));
```

Comment: Good idea, I didn’t think of that.